# How can I center a grid that seems to have a margin-left but actually doesnt?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to center my grid container on my page
I don't know why. I'm not using any `margins-left` but the containers aren't at the center.

[image]

I uploaded the code on my Git Hub. I put a border in an outside div in order to figure it out but ended up not being able to understand what was wrong.

https://github.com/JoseHelderSB/YUIDiscog

```css
header {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    padding: 5px; 
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;       }
h1 {
    font-family: Barlow;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    justify-content: center;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    
}
.info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 500px 300px ;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #2003033e;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.single-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.album-container {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;

}

#singles, #album{
    font-family: Barlow;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;

}
.single {
    width: 100px;
}
.single img{
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.single img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.title, .date, .release-info {
    font-family: Poppins;
}

.title{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.date {
    font-size: 8px;
    color: gray;
}
.release-info {
    font-size: 5px;
    color: gray;
}

.album-container img {
    width: 180px;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.album-container img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;

}

.album-title, .album-date, .album-info {
    font-family: Poppins;
}
.album-info {
    text-align: center;
}
.album-title {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;

}
.album-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
.album-text {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-inline: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
.album-container ul {
    font-size: 8px;
}
.tracklist {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.tracklist ul {
    font-family: Poppins;
}
.album-cover {
    text-align: center;
}
.corpo {
    border: black;
    border-style: solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <div class="corpo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="singles">
                    <p id="singles">SINGLES</p>
                    <div class="single-container">
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/itshappyline.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">It's happy line</p>
                            <p class="date">2004.12.24</p>
                            <p class="release-info">YUI first independant single!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/feelmysoul.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">feel my soul</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.2.23</p>
                            <p class="release-info">天使の琴声 17歳シンガーソングライター フジテレビ系月9ドラマ 主題歌でメジャーデビュー！！</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/tomorrowsway.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Tomorrow's way</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.6.22</p>
                            <p class="release-info">2005年夏休み 松竹・東急系全国ロードショー「HINOKIO」主題歌</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/life.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">LIFE</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.11.9</p>
                            <p class="release-info">18歳シンガーソングライターYUI待望のサードシングル</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/tokyo.jpeg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">TOKYO</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.1.18</p>
                            <p class="release-info">彼女の決意に涙する名曲</p>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>   
                </div>
    
                <div class="album">
                    <p id="album">ALBUM</p>
                    <div class="album-container">
                        <div class="album-cover">
                            <img src="pics/fmty.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="album-info">
                            <p class="album-title">FROM ME TO YOU</p>
                            <p class="album-date">2006.2.22</p>
                            <p class="album-text">問い合わせ殺到!!YUIファーストアルバムがついに完成しました!!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tracklist">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Merry・Go・Round</li>
                                <li>feel my soul</li>
                                <li>Ready to love</li>
                                <li>Swing of lie</li>
                                <li>LIFE</li>
                                <li>Blue wind</li>
                                <li>I can't say</li>
                            </ul>
    
                            <ul>
                                <li>Simply white</li>
                                <li>Just my way</li>
                                <li>Tomorrow's way</li>
                                <li>I know</li>
    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="singles">
                    <p id="singles">SINGLES</p>
                    <div class="single-container">
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/goodbyedays.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Good-bye days</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.6.14</p>
                            <p class="release-info">映画「タイヨウのうた」主題歌
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/irememberyou.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">I remember you</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.9.20</p>
                            <p class="release-info">せつなくも素直に描いたオリジナルソング。この秋に贈ります。</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/irememberyouLE.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">I remember you (Limited Edition)</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.9.20</p>
                            <p class="release-info">せつなくも素直に描いたオリジナルソング。この秋に贈ります。</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/rollingstar.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Rolling star</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.1.17</p>
                            <p class="release-info">とにかくゴキゲンなロックンロールナンバー!!YUI初の応援歌になりました!!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/cherry.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">CHE.R.RY</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.3.7</p>
                            <p class="release-info">☆甘酸っぱい果実のような春のうたを贈ります☆</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/cherryLE.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">CHE.R.RY <br> (Limited Edition)</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.3.7</p>
                            <p class="release-info">☆甘酸っぱい果実のような春のうたを贈ります☆</p>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>   
                </div>
    
                <div class="album">
                    <p id="album">ALBUM</p>
                    <div class="album-container">
                        <div class="album-cover">
                            <img src="pics/cbml.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="album-info">
                            <p class="album-title">CAN'T BUY MY LOVE</p>
                            <p class="album-date">2007.4.4</p>
                            <p class="album-text">私の愛するモノは　カンタンには譲れない　ＹＵＩ待望のセカンドアルバム完成</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tracklist">
                            <ul>
                                <li>How crazy</li>
                                <li>Rolling star</li>
                                <li>It’s all right</li>
                                <li>I remember you</li>
                                <li>RUIDO</li>
                                <li>Thank you My teens</li>
                            </ul>
    
                            <ul>
                                <li>Umbrella</li>
                                <li>Happy Birthday to you you</li>
                                <li>Winding road</li>
                                <li>Good-bye days</li>
                                <li>Why?</li>
    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first and then read [ask]. After that edit your question accordingly and provide debugging details in the form of a [repro]. Note, that question must be self-contained and not purely rely on external resources. Git repositories are neither acceptable nor suitable ways of providing debugging details. If the Git content changes or is removed, the question and answers would hold no further value to the community.

Comment: Remove this line: `.container {width: 500px;}` Your container *is* centered, but the content is wider than 500px, so is hanging out to the right.

Comment: In general , avoid px based measurements and work with proportions. If you must use fixed px based measurements try to keep them at one level, either the bounding parent *OR* the contained children, not both. Also keep in mind how padding, borders and margins interact with height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `width: 500px` on the container. The container is centered, but the content is hanging out to the right.

```css
header {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    padding: 5px; 
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;       }
h1 {
    font-family: Barlow;
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
body {
    background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    justify-content: center;
}
p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    
}
.info {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 500px 300px ;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #2003033e;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.single-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    column-gap: 50px;
    row-gap: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.album-container {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin: 10px;

}

#singles, #album{
    font-family: Barlow;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;

}
.single {
    width: 100px;
}
.single img{
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.single img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.title, .date, .release-info {
    font-family: Poppins;
}

.title{
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.date {
    font-size: 8px;
    color: gray;
}
.release-info {
    font-size: 5px;
    color: gray;
}

.album-container img {
    width: 180px;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.album-container img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;

}

.album-title, .album-date, .album-info {
    font-family: Poppins;
}
.album-info {
    text-align: center;
}
.album-title {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 700;

}
.album-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}
.album-text {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding-inline: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}
.album-container ul {
    font-size: 8px;
}
.tracklist {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.tracklist ul {
    font-family: Poppins;
}
.album-cover {
    text-align: center;
}
.corpo {
    border: black;
    border-style: solid;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
    <div class="corpo">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="singles">
                    <p id="singles">SINGLES</p>
                    <div class="single-container">
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/itshappyline.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">It's happy line</p>
                            <p class="date">2004.12.24</p>
                            <p class="release-info">YUI first independant single!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/feelmysoul.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">feel my soul</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.2.23</p>
                            <p class="release-info">天使の琴声 17歳シンガーソングライター フジテレビ系月9ドラマ 主題歌でメジャーデビュー！！</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/tomorrowsway.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Tomorrow's way</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.6.22</p>
                            <p class="release-info">2005年夏休み 松竹・東急系全国ロードショー「HINOKIO」主題歌</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/life.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">LIFE</p>
                            <p class="date">2005.11.9</p>
                            <p class="release-info">18歳シンガーソングライターYUI待望のサードシングル</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/tokyo.jpeg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">TOKYO</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.1.18</p>
                            <p class="release-info">彼女の決意に涙する名曲</p>
                        </div>                    
                    </div>   
                </div>
    
                <div class="album">
                    <p id="album">ALBUM</p>
                    <div class="album-container">
                        <div class="album-cover">
                            <img src="pics/fmty.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="album-info">
                            <p class="album-title">FROM ME TO YOU</p>
                            <p class="album-date">2006.2.22</p>
                            <p class="album-text">問い合わせ殺到!!YUIファーストアルバムがついに完成しました!!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tracklist">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Merry・Go・Round</li>
                                <li>feel my soul</li>
                                <li>Ready to love</li>
                                <li>Swing of lie</li>
                                <li>LIFE</li>
                                <li>Blue wind</li>
                                <li>I can't say</li>
                            </ul>
    
                            <ul>
                                <li>Simply white</li>
                                <li>Just my way</li>
                                <li>Tomorrow's way</li>
                                <li>I know</li>
    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="container">
            <div class="info">
                <div class="singles">
                    <p id="singles">SINGLES</p>
                    <div class="single-container">
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/goodbyedays.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Good-bye days</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.6.14</p>
                            <p class="release-info">映画「タイヨウのうた」主題歌
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/irememberyou.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">I remember you</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.9.20</p>
                            <p class="release-info">せつなくも素直に描いたオリジナルソング。この秋に贈ります。</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/irememberyouLE.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">I remember you (Limited Edition)</p>
                            <p class="date">2006.9.20</p>
                            <p class="release-info">せつなくも素直に描いたオリジナルソング。この秋に贈ります。</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/rollingstar.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">Rolling star</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.1.17</p>
                            <p class="release-info">とにかくゴキゲンなロックンロールナンバー!!YUI初の応援歌になりました!!</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/cherry.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">CHE.R.RY</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.3.7</p>
                            <p class="release-info">☆甘酸っぱい果実のような春のうたを贈ります☆</p>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="single">
                            <img src="pics/cherryLE.jpg" alt="feel-my-soul">
                            <p class="title">CHE.R.RY <br> (Limited Edition)</p>
                            <p class="date">2007.3.7</p>
                            <p class="release-info">☆甘酸っぱい果実のような春のうたを贈ります☆</p>
                        </div>
                      
                    </div>   
                </div>
    
                <div class="album">
                    <p id="album">ALBUM</p>
                    <div class="album-container">
                        <div class="album-cover">
                            <img src="pics/cbml.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="album-info">
                            <p class="album-title">CAN'T BUY MY LOVE</p>
                            <p class="album-date">2007.4.4</p>
                            <p class="album-text">私の愛するモノは　カンタンには譲れない　ＹＵＩ待望のセカンドアルバム完成</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tracklist">
                            <ul>
                                <li>How crazy</li>
                                <li>Rolling star</li>
                                <li>It’s all right</li>
                                <li>I remember you</li>
                                <li>RUIDO</li>
                                <li>Thank you My teens</li>
                            </ul>
    
                            <ul>
                                <li>Umbrella</li>
                                <li>Happy Birthday to you you</li>
                                <li>Winding road</li>
                                <li>Good-bye days</li>
                                <li>Why?</li>
    
                            </ul>
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    

    </div>
```